# where to put beforesave function in yii2, how to access in controller

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

i want make signup function in my app, how to create hash password using yii2.

this is my user.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "users".
 *
 * @property string $userid
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 */

class User extends ActiveRecord  implements IdentityInterface
    {

        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'users';
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['username', 'password', 'password_hash','auth_key', 'password_reset_token'], 'required'],
                [['username', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
                [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
                [['password_reset_token', 'password_hash'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
                [['username'], 'unique']
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return [
                'id' => 'ID',
                'username' => 'Username',
                'password' => 'Password',
                'password_hash' => 'Password hash',
                'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
                'password_reset_token' => 'Password Reset Token',
            ];
        }    
        /** INCLUDE USER LOGIN VALIDATION FUNCTIONS**/
            /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */


        public static function findIdentity($id)
        {
            return static::findOne($id);
        }


        public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
        {
              return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
        }


        /**
         * Finds user by username
         *
         * @param  string      $username
         * @return static|null
         */
        public static function findByUsername($username)
        {
            return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
        }

        /**
         * Finds user by password reset token
         *
         * @param  string      $token password reset token
         * @return static|null
         */
        public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
        {
            $expire = \Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
            $parts = explode('_', $token);
            $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
            if ($timestamp + $expire < time()) {
                // token expired
                return null;
            }

            return static::findOne([
                'password_reset_token' => $token
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->getPrimaryKey();
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function getAuthKey()
        {
            return $this->auth_key;
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
        {
            return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
        }

        /**
         * Validates password
         *
         * @param  string  $password password to validate
         * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
         */
        public function validatePassword($password)
        {
            return $this->password === $password;//sha1($password);
        }

        /**
         * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
         *
         * @param string $password
         */
        public function setPassword($password)
        {
            $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);//Security::generatePasswordHash($password);
        }

        /**
         * Generates "remember me" authentication key
         */
        public function generateAuthKey()
        {
            $this->auth_key = Security::generateRandomKey();
        }

        /**
         * Generates new password reset token
         */
        public function generatePasswordResetToken()
        {
            $this->password_reset_token = Security::generateRandomKey() . '_' . time();
        }

        /**
         * Removes password reset token
         */
        public function removePasswordResetToken()
        {
            $this->password_reset_token = null;
        }

    }
```

this is my UserController.php

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
$model = new User;
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

i want use setPassword function in user model, where i must put beforesave function and i need to change actionCreate function ?

thank's for help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should place it in your model, because this method is located in `yii\db\BaseActiveRecord`. Override it as mentioned in official docs:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        // Place your custom code here

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Official docs:**

- [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord beforeSave()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave%28%29-detail)

Comment: it's done bro.
i have new problem.

i try to use md5 or sha1 to encrypt password, but in validate password function value of sha1 is different with database.

Comment: If the current problem described in this question is solved, please mark the answer as accepted (you can also upvote it when you will have enough reputation)..

Comment: oh ok bro :D 

can you help this bro ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163843/validate-password-for-login-always-false-using-yii-2

Comment: @randawahyup you can see my answer on your latest question

Comment: @randawahyup I recomended you to use Yii's Hash

Comment: Sory, i'm newbie in Yii2. So which particular folder is this yii\db\BaseActiveRecord located? I'm using the advanced template. Thanks.

Comment: @JoenMarz You should place it in your model. For advanced template the paths are: `frontend/models`, `common/models` and `backend/models`. You should not modify anything under `vendor` folder, including `BaseActiveRecord` file, all changes will be lost on the next `composer update`.

Comment: But these are default paths, models can be also located inside of a module. for example: `frontend/modules/users/models/User`.

Comment: Is there `beforeInsert()` function just like beforeSave(),

Comment: @Ilyaskarim [beforeSave()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave()-detail) method has `$insert` boolean parameter, it has `true` value on insert and `false` on update. Use it depending on your case.

Comment: But events for insert and update are separated and technically you can subscribe to them outside of model, for example in behavior.