# validate password for login always false using yii 2

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

This is my `validatePassword` function in `models/user.php`

```
public function validatePassword($password)
    {
      /* var_dump(Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password)); */

        return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
};
```

this is my `setPassword` function in `models/user.php`

```
public function setPassword($password)
    {

        $this->password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }
```

to call `setPassword` function I use following `beforeSave` function in `models/user.php`:

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
            $this->setPassword($this->password);
            $this->generateAuthKey();
            $this->generatePasswordResetToken();
        return true;
    }
```

model rules `models/user.php`

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password', 'role'], 'required'],
            [['username', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['role'], 'string', 'max' => 16],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['password_reset_token'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['username'], 'unique']
        ];
    }
```

Why is the validation of my password always `false`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you made a mistake in the database. Perhaps, your password field has VARCHAR(32) (you wrote "it's normal when i used md5 password.").

```
Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);
```

This function generates the string is longer than 32 characters. For the password field, use the TEXT instead of VARCHAR(32).

Comment: i was change varchar 32 to TEXT, it's success create new user. but when login, password doesn't match with database. thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can see how to login in yii2 on http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii-2-user-login-from-database/ or another stackoverflow question [Yii Framework 2.0 Login With User Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790543/yii-framework-2-0-login-with-user-database)

hope could help you..

Comment: @randawahyup or you can find simple login like Laravel :D

Answer (score 0):

Is `$this->password` equal with db value when validatePassword performing?
I believe `setPassword()` worked for `$this->password` before validatePassword.